# Why is the outcome of txt file not as expected?

Tags: c, file, printf

The program below does not work as I expect. It is supposed to read a file with a specific format and write a file with the same values.

`sample.txt` was loaded and the output was `sample_color.txt`, see links below.

As a result, the contents of the files were not same.

Let me know how to solve it.

Input file: sample.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jogg7rxp9fk7nyi/sample.txt?dl=0

Output file: sample_color.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v1bw7tntmwlkny/sample_color.txt?dl=0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

/*****************************************************
        1.Definition of Variables
    ******************************************************/
    FILE *fpr,*fpw;  //file pointer for input&output file

    int color;//
    //int dn1,dn2,dn3,dn4,dn5;
    unsigned char r,g,b;
    float x,y,z;

    if(argc!=3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s (1)input_org.txt\n(2)write_xyz FILENAME\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("OPEN FILE NAME:%s\n",argv[1]);


    if((fpr=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
      {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(1);
      }


    if((fpw=fopen(argv[2],"w"))==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"DSM by GSI.raw\n");
        exit(1);
       }

    while(fscanf(fpr,"%f %f %f %d %d %d",&x,&y,&z,&r,&g,&b)!= EOF)
      {
        cout << x << endl;
        //color=1000000*(int)r+1000*(int)g+(int)b;
        //fprintf(fpw,"%f %f %f %d\n",x,y,z,color);
        fprintf(fpw,"%f %f %f %d %d %d\n",x,y,z,r,g,b);
       }

    fclose(fpr);
    fclose(fpw);
}
```

Comment: And if your code compiles and works, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `r, g, b` doesn't match the format specifier.

Since `char` is smaller than `int`, the input will overwrite the variables, which is why `x` has the wrong value.

You should change the type to `int` to make it work as you want:

```
int r, g, b;
```

If you are wondering about the strange rounding errors for your `float` values, you shoud read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The program is working by fixing "unsigned char -> int" .